# Poisson Distriburion

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a problem that follows Poisson distribution with $\nu=10/6$ and $t=1$. So the formula has this form:
$$\mathbb{P}(x)=\frac{(10/6)^x}{x!} e^{-10/6}.$$
I have to find the $x$ assuming that $\mathbb{P}(x) \ge 96\%$.

I try to solve this equation on Wolfram Alpha but it gives me a negative number ($-8$).
This is not acceptable because I expected a positive (I am searching for a number of cars).
Any ideas?

Comment: What is $t$? Are you sure that you have to find $x$ such that $\mathbb P(x)\ge96\%$?

Comment: You are probably asked something like find $x$ such that $\Pr(X\le x)\ge 96\%$.

Comment: Vehicles arrive at a junction, in order to swing left, create a line queue ( tail) . The number of vehicle follow Poisson distribution. The length of cycle for the traffic light (for left turns ) is 1 minute.We wish to determine the minimum length of a special strip for left turns , which ( with probability >=96%) could be containing vehicles intending to turn left . What will should be the length of the strip(number of vehicles ) to allows an average of 100 left turns of vehicle per hour?-----thats my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluating your function at the first couple integers, I get:

$$\begin{split}
f(0) &= 0.188876 \Rightarrow F(0) = 0.188876\\
f(1) &= 0.314793 \Rightarrow F(1) = 0.503669\\
f(2) &= 0.262327 \Rightarrow F(2) = 0.765996\\
f(3) &= 0.145737 \Rightarrow F(3) = 0.911733\\
f(4) &= 0.060723 \Rightarrow F(4) = 0.972456
\end{split}$$
therefore, the smallest $x$ such that $F(x) = \mathbb{P}[X \leq x] \ge 0.96$ is $x=4$.

Answer (score 1):

What
$$
\frac{(10/6)^k}{k!}e^{-10/6}
$$
is measuring is the probability that $k$ events occur in a timeframe where the expected number of events is $\frac{10}{6}$. That is, the probability of $0$ events is $e^{-10/6}$. The probability of $1$ event is $\frac{10}{6}e^{-10/6}$, the probability of $2$ events is $\frac{100}{72}e^{-10/6}$, etc. None of these probabilities is greater than $96\%$, so what is being sought is the *cumulative* probability. Now how you proceed depends on whether you want the probability of at least $k$ events or the probability of at most $k$ events to be greater than or equal to $96\%$.

Let's assume that what you want is the probability that at least $k$ events occur to be greater than or equal to $96\%$. That would be
$$
\sum_{j=k}^\infty\frac{(10/6)^j}{j!}e^{-10/6}\ge.96
$$
If $k=1$, we get the sum to be $.8111$, which is too small. So you need $k=0$.

Let's assume that what you want is the probability that at most $k$ events occur to be greater than or equal to $96\%$. That would be
$$
\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{(10/6)^j}{j!}e^{-10/6}\ge.96
$$
If $k=3$, the sum is $.9117$. If $k=4$, the sum is $.9725$. Thus, we need $k\ge4$.